# Finding gradients of functions from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: derivatives, vectors, normed-spaces

I'm trying my hand at learning differentiation of vector functions, and I'm trying to apply my knowledge of "regular" one dimensional cases to some examples, however I'm not sure if my methods are correct. Am I making errors here? (all "x" are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is n*n matrix:

$$ r(x) = ||x||_2 = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle} \\ \; \\
  \;\;\;\;\;\ \triangledown r(x) = \frac{1}{2} (x^Tx)^\frac{-1}{2} 2x = \frac{x}{||x||_2} \\ \; \\
 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;D^2 r(x) = -\frac{1}{2}(x^Tx)^{-\frac{3}{2}} x \; +\; (x^Tx)^{-\frac{1}{2}}   $$

$$\;\;\;$$

$$g(x) \;\;\ = \;\; ||x||_2^4 -2 \langle Ax, x \rangle \;\; = \;\; (\langle x,x \rangle )^2  -2 \langle Ax, x \rangle  \\ \;\\
 \triangledown g(x) \;\; = \;\; 4(x^Tx)x - 4Ax \;\; = \;\; 4||x||_2^2 x - 4Ax \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;  $$

Thank you so much for your time and input!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, technically speaking, a function $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is not a vector function, but a scalar function of several variables.

Now, let's get to the point. You can take such analogies only that far… Meaning that there are derivative rules for vector functions and derivative rules for functions of several variables, and many of them can be understood well by drawing an analogy with derivative rules for "usual" functions (scalar functions of a single variable). But taking vector or multivariate derivatives requires the respective vector or multivariate rules (so to speak). Using inappropriate rules most usually wouldn't make sense.

Here's one glaring example of such an issue in your calculations: what do you mean by $D^2r(\mathbf{x})$? Whatever you meant, the "answer" you obtained doesn't make any sense: the first term is a vector and the second term is a scalar, so you can't possibly add them together.

The computation of the gradient $\nabla r(\mathbf{x})$ is best understood if you do it component-wise. Otherwise, it's hard to explain how you got the "$2\mathbf{x}$" part in there: if it's the second part of the Chain Rule, which requires taking the derivative of the inside function, then can you explain the derivative **with respect to what** it is? Remember that the gradient operator combines partial derivatives with respect to all individual variables (components of $\mathbf{x}$).

But component-wise it's pretty easy. Let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and start with
$$r(\mathbf{x})=\|\mathbf{x}\|_2=(\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x})^{\frac{1}{2}}=(x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
Then for any variable $x_j$, $1\le j\le n$, we have
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_j}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot2x_j=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot x_j=\frac{x_j}{\|\mathbf{x}\|_2},$$
and so
$$\nabla r=\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_2},\ldots,\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_n}\right)=\left(\frac{x_1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|_2},\frac{x_2}{\|\mathbf{x}\|_2},\ldots,\frac{x_n}{\|\mathbf{x}\|_2}\right)=\frac{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)}{\|\mathbf{x}\|_2}=\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|_2}.$$
Interestingly enough, you **did** get the correct answer for this one, but without proper explanation, it's as much luck as math.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough walk-through of the process! By $D^2$ I meant the Hessian of the the function. Also, thank you for pointing out the error in that statement; I was using the product rule and in a lapse of judgement wrote the derivative of the vector $x$ as the scalar $1$ instead of a vector of $1$s.